# JSON data for Posts by Others on a Public Facebook page

Tags: json, facebook

How to retrieve Posts by Others on a public Facebook page in JSON format?

For example, [Stackoverflow Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage) page. How to get JSON data that contain posts from Stackoverflow facebook fans on the page? So, I can list them on my web, android application or etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to retrieve posts with `me/feed` and a valid access token. Should that not work, try with `pageid/feed` and a valid access token. That will return all posts (status updates included). You can filter them in many ways. This is the method with graph API. Otherwise there's FQL Query. I hope this helps.